# Django set default form values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Model as follows:

```
class TankJournal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tank = models.ForeignKey(TankProfile)
    ts = models.IntegerField(max_length=15)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
```

I also have a model form for the above model as follows:

```
class JournalForm(ModelForm):
    tank = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput()) 

    class Meta:
        model = TankJournal
        exclude = ('user','ts')
```

I want to know how to set the default value for that tank hidden field. Here is my function to show/save the form so far:

```
def addJournal(request, id=0):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    # checking if they own the tank
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['id'])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JournalForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)

            # setting the user and ts
            from time import time
            obj.ts = int(time())
            obj.user = user

            obj.tank = TankProfile.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['tank_id'])

            # saving the test
            obj.save()

    else:
        form = JournalForm()

    try:
        tank = TankProfile.objects.get(user=user, id=id)
    except TankProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/error/')
```

Answer (score 508, accepted):

You can use [`Form.initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values), which is explained [here](https://djangobook.com/tying-forms-views/#setting-initial-values).

You have two options either populate the value when calling form constructor:

```py
form = JournalForm(initial={'tank': 123})
```

or set the value in the form definition:

```py
tank = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=123)
```

Comment: And how is that variable `initial` passed to the actual form? In the actual form model, do we have to write as a parameter/argument?

Comment: wait, wut? Wut does that mean? Do you mean that, somewhere in the _init_ of the form i'd need something like: tank=initial.tank? Or something? Or would it just happen magically?

Comment: @bharal It's magic. ;-) (Or rather, Django form constructors understand the special "initial" variable and iterate through its contents without you needing to do anything extra). Personally, I prefer to specify default values in the form definition and only use the initial=... mechanism if the desired default is a dynamic value (e.g. something entered by a user, or based on their login, geographical location, etc.)

Comment: initial is not default. The initial value does not apply if the form has been bound:(.

Comment: @umnik700 , Is it secure to use forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=123) because hackers send other values ?

Comment: I swear there was a `default` keyword argument on the `Field` constructor... I can't find the documentation for it now... EDIT: I mistook it for the ModelField reference. FormFields have no `defaul` argument

Comment: Commenting here to mention another usecase where this solution of initial param will help: While sending a registration link to someone if you want to prepopulate the email/id or any other credential on the registration form then in that case you can't write that in the model itself as its dynamic rather you need to call the constructor with _initial_ param as mentioned by @umnik700. Works great!

Comment: @bharal might refer to Views using the `form_class=` shortcut, without an explicit constructor. This throws a monkeywrench into the simpler form example code. Hours of fun overriding `View.get_form` just to work around this "shortcut"

Comment: @Phlip: Don't override `View.get_form` to set initial data.  Any CBV with a FormMixin (basically all CBVs that create or edit data) can either use a class-level `initial` variable (for unchanging defaults) or you can override `FormMixin.get_initial()` to return a dict of initial values to be passed to the form's constructor (for dynamic defaults.)

Comment: `initial` value is passed from the Form to its fields when the form processes its data. But it will not work if the `initial` value is None, because the field checks it like this `if parsed_data is None and initial: ...`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when you pass in form data to the form class. If the field is missing from the form, it doesn't use the default defined in the initial dictionary.

Answer (score 59):

Other solution: Set initial after creating the form:

```
form.fields['tank'].initial = 123
```

Comment: This is the solution I needed. I have a form with default initial values, but sometimes the user comes back to a page to edit something. In that case the initial values are the previously saved values (dynamic).

Answer (score 25):

If you are creating modelform from POST values initial can be assigned this way:

```
form = SomeModelForm(request.POST, initial={"option": "10"})
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

Comment: That `or None` part is really not needed.

Comment: @smido, yes the `or None` part is needed. If the request is a GET request, request.POST will be an empty dictionary which is treated differently than `None` in the Form init method. Please review Django documentation.

Answer (score 20):

I had this other solution (I'm posting it in case someone else as me is using the following method from the model):

```
class onlyUserIsActiveField(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(onlyUserIsActiveField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['is_active'].initial = False

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['is_active']
        labels = {'is_active': 'Is Active'}
        widgets = {
            'is_active': forms.CheckboxInput( attrs={
                            'class':          'form-control bootstrap-switch',
                            'data-size':      'mini',
                            'data-on-color':  'success',
                            'data-on-text':   'Active',
                            'data-off-color': 'danger',
                            'data-off-text':  'Inactive',
                            'name':           'is_active',

            })
        }
```

The initial is definded on the `__init__` function as `self.fields['is_active'].initial = False`

Comment: thanks! this works! I tried the method in the post above by adding initial while creating the form, somehow it did not work for me.

Comment: Actually there is an easier way: Just set default value in models. For example:  alpha=models.FloatField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Enter an alpha level", default=0.05)

Answer (score 19):

As explained in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values), `initial` is not `default`.

- The **initial** value of a field is intended to be displayed in an HTML . But if the user delete this value, and finally send back a blank value for this field, the `initial` value is lost. So you do not obtain what is expected by a *default* behaviour.
- The **default** behaviour is : the value that validation process will take if `data` argument do not contain any value for the field.

To implement that, a straightforward way is to combine `initial` and `clean_<field>()`:

```
class JournalForm(ModelForm):
    tank = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=123) 

    (...)

    def clean_tank(self):
        if not self['tank'].html_name in self.data:
            return self.fields['tank'].initial
        return self.cleaned_data['tank']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add initial value and post other value you have to add the following :

`or None` after `request.POST`

```
form = JournalForm(request.POST or None,initial={'tank': 123})
```

If you want to add files or images also

```
form = JournalForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None,initial={'tank': 123})
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you:

```py
form.instance.updatedby = form.cleaned_data['updatedby'] = request.user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the need to set default values in the form during development. My solution is

```
initial={"":""}
form=ArticleModel(request.POST)
if form.has_changed():
    data = {i: form.cleaned_data[i] for i in form.changed_data}
    data.update({key: val for key, val in init_praram.items() if key not in form.changed_data})
```

use form.has_changed ,if form.fields is required you can use this method

Answer (score 0):

How I added the initial to the form:
I read **[@Sergey Golovchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/604325/15188026)** answer.

So I just added it to the form in `if request.method == 'POST':`.
But that's not where you place it, if you want to see what value it got before posting the form.
You need to put it in the form where the else is.

Example here from ***views.py***

```py
def myForm(request):
    kontext = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # You might want to use clean_data instead of initial here. I found something on a stack overflow question, and you add clean data to the Forms.py, if you want to change the post data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711229/django-forms-clean-data
        form = myModelForm(request.POST, initial={'user': request.user})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        # you need to put initial here, if you want to see the value before you post it
        form = myModelForm(initial={'user': request.user})
    kontext['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'app1/my_form.html', kontext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting another solution i came up with:

**template.html:**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.media }}
{{ form.well_id.label_tag }}
{{ form.well_id }}
{{ form.tube_id.label_tag }}
{{ form.tube_id }}
<button type="submit" >Run Analysis</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#id_well_id").select2();
        $("#id_tube_id").select2();
        
        {% if request.method == 'GET' %} // Because id_tube_id is a 'required' form field, we need to initialize a null parameter to show the placeholder.
        $("#id_tube_id").val(null);
        $("#id_tube_id").trigger('change');
        {% endif %}
    });
</script>
```

The reasoning behind using this method and not the pure python based methods posted above was that I had set the tube_id field to be a required form field but not the well_id field. Apparently, if you assign a field to be required, it is being prefilled with the first value in your list of choices, unless specified otherwise by an initial value.
But in my case, i didn't want an initial value - i just wanted the initial value to be None. Django can assign a choice as an initial value only if it allready exists in your list of choices, so if you would assign None as an initial value, it would just show the first item on the list.

The solution is therefore to assign an initial value through javascript (in my case, i needed it to happen only if request.method == 'GET').