# How to give initial value in modelform

Tags: django, google-app-engine

How do I assign initial values to fields inside a ModelForm? eg:

```
class Form1(forms.Form):
    title=forms.CharField(initial="hello")
```

What will be the equivalent for this using modelForm whose basic syntax is something like:

```
class Form2(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=SomeModel
        fields=('title',)
```

What I am trying to do is generate a CRUD. Since I am doing it in an appengine project I can't use generic views. Appengine has provided us `djangoforms.ModelForm` which works just like the django's `ModelForm` but uses appengine's datastore.

I need the above functionality to do the "edit" part.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/604266/212218

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Normally you would pass the model object you are editing as instance keyword arg to the form:
`Form2(instance = somemodelobject)`, but I don't know if it works on GAE.
You can always pass initial dictionary to your form's constructor, like

```
Form2(initial = {"title": "blahblah"})
```

Answer (score 4):

Model Form defaults are taken from the model itself. For example:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=45, default="hello")
```

You don't need to make any changes to your ModelForm:

```
class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```