# Django - Modelform - pre-set one of the fields

Tags: django, modelform

How can you pre-define one of the fields in a ModelForm?

When creating a ModelForm, you can choose which fields to display in your browser. Though, I would like to preset one of them.

thanks to all !

Comment: This is described in the documentation of ModelForm [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give initial value in modelform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054546/how-to-give-initial-value-in-modelform)