# make the user in a model default to the current user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ClientDetails(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

How do I make `created_by` default to the currently logged in user?

*(I want to do this so I can hide it in the admin view mainly but also because when I save an instance I don't want to be filling it every time)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you need to get the currently logged in user from a `request` object you cannot get it in the model's `save`-method,but you can eg override the model admin's `save_model`-method:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        user = request.user 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not change or not instance.created_by:
            instance.created_by = user
        instance.modified_by = user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

Comment: can I just drop this in one of my admin views? (obviously after changing created_by and modified_by). Any chance you can break this down for us?

Comment: this is the most useful solution, because you get to use "request", can't believe I missed it here http://django.me/save_model

Comment: how we remove created_by dropdown from form??

Answer (score 15):

You have to override `get_changeform_initial_data` method in your model Admin class in `admin.py` as follows:

```
# admin.py

class ClientDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        get_data = super(ClientDetailsAdmin, self).get_changeform_initial_data(request)
        get_data['created_by'] = request.user.pk
        return get_data

admin.site.register(ClientDetails, ClientDetailsAdmin)
```

In such way you obtain the most elegant solution since the `created_by` field is filed up when you create new record.

Comment: This is very nice! Could this be extended to work for `updated_by` on every update? (Ideally less messily than overriding `ModelAdmin._changeform_view`, and pre-render like this, so not overriding `save_model`.)

Comment: Overriding `formfield_for_foreignkey` you can force the queryset to be the current user only, which is close but not as nice as the above, which permits a user to override this if necessary. (Idea from [here](https://timonweb.com/posts/auto-select-current-user-in-django-admin-form/).)

Comment: **NOTE:** will work on new ones, not on existing ones

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue recently, this is from my views.py file

```
def CircleAdd(request):

    form = CircleAddForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        Circle = form.save(commit=False)
        Circle.Author = request.user
        Circle = Circle.save()
```

And then I had a form for the 'circles' model, which was just a wrapper really (forms.py)

```
class CircleAddForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Circle
```

Remember to import the form in your view!

Edit: not even sure if you even need to bother with the separate form, the key bit is the fake commit, followed by the real

Comment: not to sure what forms.py is (still new to django) I was just hoping to do this in the admin interface

Comment: I'm presuming if I can get it to default in models.py then it will default in the admin and site views as well

Comment: on to forms now and your answer now makes sense

Comment: It is just unfortunate that in Django you have to write the same code in all views for models which require the current user. I'm hoping to find a better way but until then this is the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the accepted answer, if you're looking to do this with Class Based views, you can follow the instructions in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user), overriding the `form_valid()` method on the class view:

```
# views.py

from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class CreateClient(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(CreateClient, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Note that this does not work if the field is a required field.

Answer (score 2):

Normal modelfields have a default argument. But ForeignKeys do not as far as I know, so I guess you need to work with a [post_save](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal.

Comment: +1, but if it were me i will just override the save() function :)

Comment: Then I would have to override the admin default save function wouldn't I?

Comment: Present versions of Django certainly allows defaults for foreign keys.  I am not sure that they ever didn't.  So if anyone comes by and read this reply today, at best it should be considered out dated.

Answer (score 1):

I found:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CurrentUserField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CurrentUserField, self).__init__(User, null=True, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
        super(CurrentUserField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
        registry = registration.FieldRegistry()
        registry.add_field(cls, self)

class ClientDetails(models.Model):
    created_by = CurrentUserField()
...
```

from [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=lJwOcsZq5g4C&lpg=PP1&dq=pro%20django&pg=PA257#v=onepage&q&f=false). But isn't there an easier way?

Comment: + I don't know how to import `registration`

Comment: You should read the book further, there's more you need, including the registration and a middleware!