# request.user in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django models to create the fields for a form. I would like to have the user's username automatically detected in and be filled out, this way I can hide it in my form (instead of having them choose their username from a long list that has everyones username). To do this I am using:

```
current_user = request.user
```

and then setting the default to current_user. However, I keep getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

I'm assuming you can't use requests in Django models, but is there anyway to get around this? Here is the relevant sections of my models.py file:

```
class StockTickerSymbol(models.Model):
    StockName = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    current_user = request.user
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=current_user)
```

Anyone know how I can use requests in my models, or somehow call the variable current_user?

Comment: Related or duplicate: [make the user in a model default to the current user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670783/make-the-user-in-a-model-default-to-the-current-user).

Comment: You can't use *anything*, anywhere in Python at all, unless it is somehow passed to it.

Answer (score 9):

Here you haven't imported request in that model class scope. This is how you can get user:

```
# model

class StockTickerSymbol(models.Model):
    StockName = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def save(self,**kwargs):
      if kwargs.has_key('request') and self.user is None:
            request = kwargs.pop('request')
            self.user= request.user
      super(StockTickerSymbol, self).save(**kwargs)

#views:

def post(self, request):
   if form.is_valid():                         
       sts=StockTickerSymbol()
       sts.StockName= form.cleaned_data['StockName']
       if form.cleaned_data['user'] is None: #null check
          sts.save(request=request)
       else:
          sts.user= form.cleaned_data['user']
          sts.save(request=request)
```

For modelform:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def save(self, commit=True ,*args, **kwargs):
        request = None
        if kwargs.has_key('request'):
            request = kwargs.pop('request')
        m = super(SomeForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
        if m.user is None and request is not None:
            m.user= request.user
            m.save()
```

in views:

```
def post(self, request):
   if form.is_valid():  
      form.save(request=request)
      return ...
```

Comment: Ok, I've added the `def save` bit to my models.py, but I'm not entirely sure where to add the views code. [Here](http://pastebin.com/4RJ4Adjc) is my relevant views.py file. Where exactly would the  code go?

Comment: very helpful, thanks - needed requests to set a `message`.. though maybe I should be doing that in `post_save` anyway...