# Extend a model using OneToOneField

Tags: django

I'm trying to extend [django-taggit](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit) `Tag` model to have an `added_by` (ForeignKey to User) field on it, so I can query all tags added by a particular user. So, I have created an app and in models.py there I have created another model, called `MyTag` and I have a OneToOneField to `Tag` on it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from taggit.models import Tag


class MyTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.OneToOneField(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Tag)
def create_tag(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        MyTag.objects.create(tag=instance, added_by=???)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Tag)
def save_tag(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.mytag.save()
```

The issue is, I can't access `request.user` from inside models.py.

How do I overcome the issue, i.e. how do I  properly extend django-taggit's `Tag` model to have added_by field on it?

Comment: your question may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25717430/11225821)

Comment: Have you looked into extending the `Tag` model and then overriding the `save()` method to accept `request.user`? This depends on who or how `Tag` model is used though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using *inheritance* instead of OneToOneField.

```py
from taggit.models import Tag

class MyTag(Tag):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now the **MyTag** model inherits all the properties and methods of the **Tag** model. More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Now to create a new instance of MyTag you can do in your view:

```py
MyTag.objects.create(added_by=request.user , [... other Tag properties])
```