# Django - Setting default owner as the logged in user

Tags: django, python-2.7

This is a bump post. I have tried various ways and went through all examples here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672123/6274043
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5529770/6274043
- [How do you specify a default for a Django ForeignKey Model or AdminModel field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937954/how-do-you-specify-a-default-for-a-django-foreignkey-model-or-adminmodel-field)

and all doesn't seem to work for me.

```
# models.py in main/ app
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Mileage(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    ... #other parameters

#admin.py
class MileageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['date', ...]

    def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        user = request.user 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.owner= user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance

    #views.py
    def home(request):
        form = MileageForm(request.POST or None)    
        context = {"form": form}

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()

            form = MileageForm()
            context = {"form": form}

        return render(request, 'record_trip.html', context)
```

I am trying to set the default `owner` as the logged in user. I tried doing it in `ModelAdmin` like how other posts do but doesn't seem to work. Can any kind soul point out where am I doing it wrong?

It keeps throwing `IntegrityError owner_id cannot be null`.

Please pardon me if I made elementary mistakes above. I started coding half a year ago for leisure.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly. You are trying to set the logged-in user as the default owner of a newly created model?

Currently, you are only setting `created_by` and `modified_by` to default to the logged-in user.

```
#admin.py
class MileageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        user = request.user 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not change or not instance.created_by:
            instance.created_by = user
        instance.modified_by = user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

But those two fields do not even exist in you example model

```
class Mileage(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    ... #other parameters
```

However, you are never actually setting `instance.owner` to be the `request.user`. So `instance.owner` remains to be `None`, that's why Django complains.

You need to set it before `save()`ing your instance.

```
class MileageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        instance.owner = request.user

        if not change or not instance.created_by:
            instance.created_by = request.user
        instance.modified_by = request.user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Yes you are right I copied blindly. I edited my code accordingly to your comment and is shown above. Basically I kept the 'owner' parameters and added in the 'instance.owner=user'. But it still throws the same error. What have I missed?

Comment: Updated my answer. Remove `instance = form.save(commit=False)` that is overwriting the `instance` you are receiving as a method argument.

Comment: No luck, it still throws the same error. I wonder if the 'form.save()' in views.py has any influence in this. Could that conflict the instantiation as well?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the model's save method is getting called somewhere before you've had a chance to set it to the request.user.

You could either find out where that's happening (and perhaps other answers might have a better idea of where that's happening?) or if you wanted a shortcut, you could set the `owner` attribute to not be a required field, trusting that you'll set it later.

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

That way, creating the model without the owner wouldn't throw up an integrity error, but you could trust that the owner attribute would eventually be set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But for some reason it still throws the same error. I'm beginning to suspect 'form.save()' in views.py has something to do with this. When I trace back the error log it highlights that line. Any advise here?

Comment: Hmm that's very strange that you'd still be getting the "Cannot be null" error after specifying explicitly that it can be. Shot in the dark: Any chance you didn't run makemigrations and migrate? If not, my apologies: I should have specified that this would also be required.

Comment: yes it works now. But like you said it sets it as a null by default. I would still require the request.user input because eventually I would wanna publish a table on the site displaying the user's transaction. This is ripping my hair off, I can't seem to identify where I have missed out.