# Django: set user creating a post (creator of a row) automatically as creator/author

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make it so that when creating a new post in a blog using Django the admin (user) who's created it is set automatically as its author. This is my code so far (which doesn't work, the last line gives an error):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    notable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False, blank=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(
                blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' On save, update timestamps '''
    if not self.id:
         self.created = datetime.today()
         self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    self.modified = datetime.today()            
    return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Can anyone help me please?

There's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414473/how-to-assign-currently-logged-in-user-as-default-value-for-a-model-field) here in Stack Overflow but it doesn't entirely answer my question as it still leaves the option to select another user and not have it set automatically, which is what I truly want.

Comment: `return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` should be `return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Also you don't need to override `save()` to update timestamps. See [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add).