# Getting the request.user form pre_save in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.4

I have a global `pre_save` signal where I need to get the current logged in user i.e `request.user`.

I have tried the following **which seems to work** however, it looks like a bad idea...

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    import inspect

    for frame_record in inspect.stack():
        if frame_record[3] == 'get_response':
            request = frame_record[0].f_locals['request']
            break
        else:
            request = None
    print(request.user) <--- correct user is given
```

Are there any potential issues with above? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Using Python 3.4 and Django 1.8.4

Comment: did you tried debugging the code if request is there or not?

Comment: @AjayGupta No but this works but can I rely on it? If not are there better options?

Comment: Potential issues are, when you create model from Django shell, from management command or any other method.

Comment: Also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414473/how-to-assign-currently-logged-in-user-as-default-value-for-a-model-field).

Comment: @Falcon1 this is a good option, i don't see any better way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think middleware will be better solution. Check this project to get the idea [django-cuser](https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-cuser/blob/master/cuser/middleware.py).

btw. Inspecting stack to get the request is brilliant example of how can python be abused and still solve problems :)