# how to add post to django user model using foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-models

i created a model

```
class ThisUser(models.Model):
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     message = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.user
```

I want to store message specifically for the user who is authenticated.
right now this will give me all user who is available in my user model.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign currently logged in user as default value for a model field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414473/how-to-assign-currently-logged-in-user-as-default-value-for-a-model-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are suppose to take care of that at view level and not model level,
for example this is how I create a new Album:

```
@login_required
def make_album(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AlbumCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_album = core_models.Album(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], description=form.cleaned_data['description'], user=request.user)`
```

Answer (score 1):

`user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Instead of foriegn key use one to one relation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.user.id` to get user's id for further use.