# How can you manually render a form field with its initial value set?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, form-fields

I'm trying to render a form's fields manually so that my designer colleagues could manipulate the input elements within the HTML instead of struggling in Python source.

ie. Instead of declaring form fields like this...

```
            {{ form.first_name }}
```

.. I actually do ...

```
            <label for="id_first_name">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{  form.first_name.somehow_get_initial_value_here }}" name="first_name" id="id_first_name" class="blabla" maxlength="30" >
            {% if form.first_name.errors %}<span>*** {{ form.first_name.errors|join:", " }}</span>{% endif %}
```

Problem is that there seems to be no way to get the initial value of the field in the second method. **{{ form.first_name }}** statement does render the input element with the proper initial value but somehow there is nothing like **{{ form.first_name.initial_value }}** field when you want to render the form manually.

Comment: The input tag has a `value` attribute. `     <input type="text" maxlength="30" name="first_name" id="id_first_name" class="blabla" value="initial value">` for example. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks but that initial value comes from the server side, dynamically. Edited the code sample to be more clear.

Comment: If you provided `first_name` in the `initial` dict when creating the form class instance, the value will automatically be provided in `{{ form.first_name }}` the first time the form is displayed.

Comment: if the only issue is to put styles you can add the css classes in the form fields in your code.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values/604325#604325

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an interesting long standing ticket about this very issue. There is sample code to implement a template filter in the comments that should do what you need:

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10427

Comment: for everyone who's here from google:
`<input value="{{ form.field_name.value }}">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input value="{{form.name.data|default_if_none:'my_defaut_value'}}" ... />
```

You will have to use `default_if_none` because the implicit value of a bound field will not be stored in `data.` [More details here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10427)

Comment: Maybe I missed something but "form.field.data" comes up None everytime.

Comment: Yeah, I see now that it raises some issues also on my side. It works when the form comes in error mode tho :P . But, as at the end of my answer and as the first guy responded, more details (if you have the nerv and tme to read the full ticket) are found in that ticket ;)