# Django template format string

Tags: python, django, templates, formatting

I have a form that has a field:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.Form):
    nickname = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label=_('Your nickname'), required=False)
```

Then in a template I want to put a user's nickname value. I am using `django-widget-tweaks`.

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<label>Your nickname</label> {{ form.nickname|append_attr:"value:"|add:"request.user" }}
```

In this case I get an empty string instead of the value.

```
<label>Your nickname</label> {{ form.nickname|append_attr:"value:request.user" }}
```

And in this case I get a string "request.user" instead of the value of `request.user`.

How can I add a value from my database to this field?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/604325/37386

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `initial` argument, which you can pass in the value you want to use to prepopulate  the element. You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) in the docs, or from a related SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/604325/37386

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ form.nickname|attr:"value:request.user" }
```