# Default Modelform field value initially set

Tags: django, default-value, django-forms

Im trying to specify a default value for my form field `domainNm` when the form is initially loaded.

I have:
**form**

```
   class SubmitDomain(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Tld #Create form based off Model for Tld
            fields = ['domainNm',]

    def clean_domainNm(self):
        cleanedDomainName = self.cleaned_data.get('domainNm')
        if Tld.objects.filter(domainNm=cleanedDomainName).exists():
            errorMsg = u"Sorry that domain is not available."
            raise ValidationError(errorMsg)
        else:
            return cleanedDomainName

    ## This creates the form.
    form = SubmitDomain()
```

**Model**

```
class Tld(models.Model):
    domainNm = models.CharField( )   #add a call in here?
```

I tried searching google a lot before posting this, but cannot seem to find an example of something so basic.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SubmitDomain(ModelForm):
    domainNm = forms.CharField(initial=u'Initial value')
    class Meta:
        model = Tld #Create form based off Model for Tld
        fields = ['domainNm',]
```

Comment: I was trying this "initial"  ,but it wasn't working, must have been doing something wrong here. Thanks!