# Django - how to validate custom form for adding many similar entries at once

Tags: python, django

I have a model called "occurrence" which tracks occurrences of species at different sites.  The model has 4 fields.

```
 refID (foreign key to the reference source of data)
 siteID (foreign key to site)
 speciesID (foreign key to species)
 abundance (integer)
```

I know I could create a model-form to add an entry.  But modelforms would be tedious because, most of the time I want to enter data for dozens or hundreds of species with the same combination of siteID and refID.  I have created my own data entry form in the template to select a refID and siteID, and use jQuery to add new lines for speciesID and abundance. Thus, I have a single refID + siteID combination, with many speciesIDs + abundance lines. Then, the idea is to iterate over all the added lines and save all the occurrences in the view.

The problem is that validation of this form is quite difficult, as I have to do everything "manually" in the view.  This seems like it might be a common problem, so I wonder.....

Am I missing a pre-existing Django solution here?

Comment: its striking me now that I could accomplish the same thing by using a model form, and by having refID and siteID be "sticky" (i.e. remember their previous values).  I am looking into this now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution to this problem turned out to be using a modelform to save a single instance at a time. I made the refID and siteID fields "sticky" by passing back the saved values for those fields to the reloaded form using the "[initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values#answer-604325)" argument to the modelform.  This way, I can use all the built in form validation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're, as far as I understand your question.

have a look at [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: Thanks for this....I was overlooking Formsets. In my particular case I solved the problem by using a modelform, and passing back the initial values when I reloaded the modelform after a successful save, but Formsets would be a good solution as well.