# Get the value from a placeholder to send it in the form django

Tags: python, django, forms, models, placeholder

I was using a default value in the model

```
constitucional_64 = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True,blank=True,default='negado')
```

The problem is the I need to delete the value from the input when I click on it, I'm using placeholders in my ModelForm

```
class ExpedienteInicialform(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = ExpedienteConsultaInicial
    widgets = {
        'constitucional_64': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'negado'}),
    }
```

But I need to get the value 'negado' to send the to the database, the placeholder works fine, the problem is that I don't get the value in the POST.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django set default form values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `placeholder`, use `value`.

```
'constitucional_64': forms.TextInput(attrs={'value': 'negado'}),
```