# How I can use correctly django ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm a newbie and right now I'm using Django forms to show some fields.  One of these fields is a ModelChoiceField this show correctly model data, but I don´t know how I can fill a CharField later of select a option in the ModelChoiceField.

How I can make  send  the value of option selected for obtain the data that i need for later show this in a CharField, this is possible make directly from a djangoForm or do I need a new view to return the value?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you want I think:

1. Provide an initial value for your form value.
2. Bind your form to some data.

See this related stack overflow to provide [initial values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values).

See Django's documentation on [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/) for binding data. There are two kinds of form states: `bound` and `unbound`. To create a bound form, you just need to create an instance of your form with some data: `MyForm({'data-key1': 'data-value1', ...})`.