# Django ManyToMany all values by default

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    provinces = models.ManyToManyField('Province', related_name='formats')
```

By default, products can be sold in every province. How can I define the model "Product" so that every product created has all provinces by default?

Thanks!

Comment: This could do the job: [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save)

Answer (score 7):

Use the default key. You can't directly set default model values to an iterable like a list, so wrap them in a callable, as the Django documentation advises: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/

```
def allProvinces():
    return provincesList

provinces = models.ManyToManyField('Province', related_name='formats', default=allProvinces)
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I stumbled onto this answer first and eventually [this (old and "unresolved") ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2750). I personally had to use the post_save signal suggered by @Gocht

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) signal.

You can not use default field option for many-to-may fields as mentioned [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/999)

Comment: You can totally use `default`, this is just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly add a list to M2M directly, you should first get the objects :

```
def allProvinces():
    provinceList = Province.objects.all()
    return provinceList
```

And then add the default=allProvinces :)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32068983/1581629 I did this:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created_flag = False
        if not self.pk:
            created_flag = True
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created_flag:
            self.provinces = Province.objects.all()
```