# The right way to set the default value of a ManyToMany field in django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

What is the right way to set the default value of a many2many field? This is what I tried below but it is not working. I know that I could override the save method, but wouldn't that be called every time the model gets updated? I want to only set the initial values of the model every time an instance is created.

```
def default_values():
     return [c.id for c in SomeOtherModel.objects.filter(otherfield__isnull = True)]


class SomeModel(models.Model):
    somefield = models.ManyToManyField('SomeField', default=default_values)
    semeotherfield = models.ForeignKey('SomeOtherField')
```

I am using django 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override save method, and inside that insert a check if primary key is empty or not. If it's empty - this is creation of object.

Also you can connect to post save signal - there is attribute telling you if this is creation of object or not.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. But do you know why the above method is not working?

Comment: I get this error now: " [] needs to have a value for field [] before this many-to-many relationship can be used. ". My save method is above.

Comment: It worked, thanks, I just had to save the model before populating the field.

Comment: @JiydaMoussa can I see how you made it work?

Answer (score 4):

The method, mentioned in the question, is not working because `ManyToManyField` can not have a value when being saved (values must be added with the `RelatedManager`). So the `default` option for a `ManyToManyField` is not used when saving the object (when calling `<object>.save()`, or other): even if it is set (e.g. to a callable returning an object list), the field will be set to an empty list when saving.

According to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2750):

> `default` option value is used in Django Form set up to edit this
>   object. In particular, in Django Admin, the multivalue drop-down will
>   include for the field, that will contain all the objects returned by
>   the callable defined as the default value - and they will be all
>   selected. If the user saves the object without any edit (by pushing
>   the form's "save" button), then the field will indeed be set to all
>   the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the **init** method of the model but that wouldnot allow you to set m2m.

you can override the init of the modelform like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'initial' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['initial'] = {}
    kwargs['initial'].update(product_template_admin_initial_values())
    super(ProductTemplateAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But that will not allow to use the request.

If you depend on the request you can use the admin get_changeform_initial_data

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    return {'name': 'custom_initial_value'}
```

You can call a method with the request as argument and return a dictionary. the m2m default should be a list

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set a default in the admin page for a M2M list, you can do something like this. For example, to set the default of managed_by to the current user:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request: HttpRequest):
        defaults = super().get_changeform_initial_data(request)
        defaults['managed_by'] = [request.user]
        return defaults
```

Here we also call `super().get_changeform_initial_data` so that we don't loose the defaults that Django sets.