# Django, User can have more than one role in the application, 3 types of User

Tags: python, django, django-models

As title, I have 3 types of User and each User can have more than one role.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CASCADE
from hospital.models import Hospital

class Role(models.Model):
    '''
  The Role entries are managed by the system,
  automatically created via a Django data migration.
  '''
    DOCTOR = 1
    DIRECTOR = 2
    PATIENT = 3

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (DOCTOR, 'doctor'),
        (DIRECTOR, 'director'),
        (PATIENT, 'patient'),

    )

    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_id_display()


class User(AbstractUser):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.roles


class Doctor(models.Model):
    # role = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    career = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length = 1000)

class Director(models.Model):
    # role = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor)

class Patient(models.Model):
    # personal information like above.
```

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

I'm creating a model, but I do not know how to set the key.

I made it by referring to the above site. The director owns the doctor and can authorize it.

But I do not know how to give a key to a doctor or director.

If you I to comment, I get an error.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to set the default `roles` for the 3 derived classes.

Taking slight inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32068983/2689986).

Since `roles` is a many-to-many relation, you can override the model's `save` method (you can use signals for this as well, but wouldn't recommend that in your case).

e.g.

```
class Doctor(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id: # object creation
            should_add_role = True
        super(Doctor, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # do the usual
        if should_add_role: # add our defaults
            self.roles.add(Role.objects.get_or_create(id=Role.DOCTOR))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I do not know your intentions. Can you explain in more detail? Where should I call the save function? Where should self be defined?

Comment: You don't have to call `.save` explicitly. We're overriding default behaviour to add our custom logic. The method is defined (overriding the default method) under the model class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
When I create a specific role (eg doctor) in the user model, I want to make DoctorProfile model instance automatically. But I do not know how to do it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. When & where do you want to create the model instance? And for what purposes?

Comment: Sorry for my insufficient explanation. When i make User model instance automatically, 
If i create an instance of the User model, i want to make userprofile that corresponds to that role.
(for example, i have created a user instance with a role  doctor , automatically make doctorprofile instance) what should i do?

Comment: In that case, you should use the `post_save` signal on your user model and according to the role of that instance, create the corresponding profile instance. See this example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13016982/2689986.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!!