# Django form is not rendered properly after setting initial values dynamically

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to render a form where more then one field are initialized dynamically based on a parameter passed from view to form.
I am setting the initial value at the form's **init** method and it seems to work fine as far as assigning the values to field elements is considered.
When I print the form, I can see those values attached to appropriate field element.
The issue is that those values does not show up when rendered.

My View is:

```
def zoneinfo(request):
    siteId = request.GET.get('siteId')
    form = PostForm(site = siteId.upper())
    print form
    return render(request, 'details.html', {'form': form})
```

code in form.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    siteId =  kwargs.pop('site', None)
    super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if siteId:
        siteInfo = getSiteInfo(siteId.upper())
        self.fields['city'] = forms.CharField(max_length=25, initial=siteInfo['city'])
        self.fields['address'] = forms.CharField(max_length=25, initial=siteInfo['address'])
        self.fields['state'] = forms.CharField(max_length=50, initial=siteInfo['state'])
        self.fields['zip'] = forms.CharField(max_length=10, initial=siteInfo['zip'])
```

details.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<form action = "/zones/add" id="addNewZoneForm1" method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
<!-- <form  id="addNewSite" method='post'>{% csrf_token %} -->
    <fieldset>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
            {{ form.as_table }}
      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>


</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getSite(value){
        $.ajax({
             url: "sites/getinfo?siteId="+value,
             type: "get",
        })
    }
</script>
```

where Print form returns :

```
<tr><th><label for="id_site">Site:</label></th><td><select id="id_site" name="site" onChange="getSite(this.value);">
<option value="initialValue">----Select Site----</option>
<option value="abc">ABC</option>
<option value="xyz">XYZ</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_city">City:</label></th><td><input id="id_city" maxlength="25" name="city" type="text" value="SAN" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_address">Address:</label></th><td><input id="id_address" maxlength="25" name="address" type="text" value="SAN" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_state">State:</label></th><td><input id="id_state" maxlength="50" name="state" type="text" value="SAN" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_zip">Zip:</label></th><td><input id="id_zip" maxlength="10" name="zip" type="text" value="10000001" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_description">Description:</label></th><td><textarea cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" rows="10">
</textarea></td></tr>
```

We can see in the html out put that the fields have values associated but they are not rendered in the view.
There is no error that I am getting, just a form with empty fields

EDIT: I tired to print return `render(request, 'details.html', {'form': form})` on console and the output contains the values for the fields. Not sure why those values are not visible on the web page.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values

Comment: I tried to follow those examples but it does not apply to a successful result. I still face the same issue. Moreover it seems a bit odd to define so many fields while initializing the form. Also I am not using modelForms. It is just a basic form, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Are you somehow expecting your Ajax getSite call to change the form you have already rendered?

Comment: What I want to achieve is: on the html page user will get an dropdown to select an option based on which I want to populate remaining fields. So I am trying to fetch data from db based on the dropdown option selected and I am successful in that. But the form is not rendering based on the new values. One clarification I would like to make is I have written two views. The first one renders the plain form. The second view which I have shown here is the one that should render with updated values.

Comment: Yes but all your JS is doing is making a GET to the view. It's not doing anything at all with the result. JS doesn't magically update your HTML for you, you'd need to define a success method in your ajax call and do something with the result.

Comment: OK, I understood. I was not returning the data from html response to the page. adding below to the getSite made it to work. Thanks
success: function(data){
              $( "#content" ).html(data);
             }

Answer (score 0):

Modified the getSite code and it worked exactly as I wanted

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getSite(value){
        $.ajax({
             url: "/zones/info?siteId="+value,
             type: "get",
             success: function(data){
                $( "#content" ).html(data);
             }
        })
    }
</script>
```