# How to set an input in a form to have a default based on the users selection Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am using Django to create an app. I have a list of objects and a user can select one and go to a page with the details of that object on it, they can then change these details. However, at the moment, the form which is used to change the details asks the user to enter the name of the object before changing the details. I would like it to have a default value already entered, this default value should be the one the user selected and viewed on the previous page i.e. the user selects 'object1', they go to the form to change the information for 'object1' and at the top of that form there is a label which says 'Object name' and the input box has 'object1' in it without the user doing anything to it. Here is some of my code, I hope this all makes sense. Has anyone got any suggestions on how I could do this? I'm thinking I could use RESTful API URLs, so the url could be something like `/details/2/change_date` then maybe it could access the name for id 2?

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^details/$', Info.as_view(), name="server_details"),
    url(r'^details/([0-9]+)/$', GetDetails.as_view(), name="details"),
    url(r'^change_date/$', ChangeDateFormView.as_view(), name="change_date"),
]
```

Views.py

```
class ChangeDateFormView(FormView):

def get_form_class(self):
    return ChangeDateForm

def get_template_names(self):
    return 'change_date.html'

# Renders a form on GET and processes it on POST.
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    if form.is_valid():
        form_data = form.cleaned_data
        name = form.data['name']
        new_date = form_data['new_date']
        confirm_new_date = form_data['confirm_new_date']

        if new_date != confirm_new_date:
            form._errors["new_date"] = "Dates do not match"
            return self.form_invalid(form)

        elif MyObjects.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
            MyObjects.objects.filter(name=name).update(date=new_date)
            return render(request, 'change_data_success.html', {})

        else:
            form.errors['name'] = "doesn't exists"
            return self.form_invalid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Template

```
<form action="{% url "change_date" %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group cf">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            {% render_field form.name type="name" class+="form-control" placeholder="name" %}
            <span style="color: #FF0000">{{ form.name.errors }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group cf">
        <label for="date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">New date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            {% render_field form.new_date type="date" class+="form-control" %}
            <span style="color: #FF0000">{{ form.new_date.errors }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group cf">
        <label for="confirm date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm date:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            {% render_field form.confirm_new_date type="date" class+="form-control" %}
            <span style="color: #FF0000">{{ form.confirm_new_date.errors }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: There's no point using a FormView here; you've bypassed all its functionality by overriding `get` and `post`.

Comment: And all the validation you're currently doing in `post` should be done in the form's `clean` methods anyway.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, you are right, I will fix that

Comment: This has been covered before I believe:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values

Comment: @bmbbigbang do you not use initial when you know the value you want is?  I want the value shown to be the one that the user selected on a previous page so I wouldn't know the value and it will change. I'm probably wrong.

Comment: that's called a "variable"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using RESTful URLs. https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-rest-framework-quick-start/

Then my change_details page can use the id that the details page uses.