# set initial values of ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I use `"msignup"` model for user signups. after signup is complete which works just fine, in the profile of the user I want to let them change some basic information that they used during the signup (which are saved in database in `msignup` model) using modelform named "`accountSettingsForm`". 
Obviously the original user information must be there in the "`accountSettingsForm` " and the user would change any piece of information he/she likes. 
I know it is possible to set the initial value of the accountSettingsForm:

```
form = accountSettingsForm(initial={'someFieldName':snomeVariable})
```

But I assume there is a better way of doing this that I don't know about.
Probably using `__init__` methods is more appropriate.
Any helps will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values

Comment: Why don't you think using `initial` is appropriate?

Comment: @rrauenza definitely related but my question is how to get the initial value from the database dynamicly and not setting the default values for the form.

Comment: @solarissmoke It seems verbose! usually Django has some magic which summarizes 10 lines into just two!

Comment: @rrauenza When I use initial, since the modelform has a subset of fields of the model, it gives me 'required' error for absent fields that I don't want to update.

Comment: You can do it in `__init__`, but you'll still be modifying the `initial` argument.

Comment: I kinda figured out a way I don know if its good practice or not.

Comment: @rrauenza `mi = msignup.objects.get(pk=userID) 
        form = accountSettingsForm(instance=mi)`

Comment: Doesn't that setup the form for updating that object's instance?

Comment: exactly I want to update that certain instance of the object! is it good practice? Maybe I worry too much about good practice!