# Problem setting initial Django ModelForm field value

Tags: python, django

I’m trying to set the default value in the form (the field is the date for publishing the article “public”), but when loading the form on the page, the field is empty. I tried to set the default value in the "header" field (any value, not necessarily today's date) - also does not appear.

**form:**

```
from main.models import Article
from datetime import datetime


class AddArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['publish'].initial = datetime.now()

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title', 'author', 'body', 'publish', 'status')
        labels = {
            'body': 'Text'
        }
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-form'}),
            'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'md-form'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'md-textarea', 'rows': 3}),
            'publish': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'md-form'}),
            'status': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select'})

        }
```

**views:**

```
def add_article(request):
    form = AddArticleForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/articles/')
    args = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'html/add_article.html', args)
```

**html:**

```
...
<form action="." method="post" class="add-article">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="md-form">
                    {% if field.name != 'status' and field.name != 'publish' %}
                        <label for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label> {{ field }}
                    {% else %}
                         <label for="{{ field.name }}"></label> {{ field }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-pink btn-block">Share</button>
        </form>
...
```

[image: The form]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django set default form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values)

Comment: @shaik-moeed , no. I am tryed this methods.

Comment: any answers helpful?

Comment: @shaik-moeed , no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the issue is you are sending `request.POST` as argument to the form class even if it is a GET request.

```
form = AddArticleForm(request.POST)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So I suggest to update the view like this:

```
def add_article(request):
    form = AddArticleForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/articles/')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'html/add_article.html', context)
```

So that, it will handle `POST` requests explicitly, and send `request.POST` as argument only if there is `request.POST`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add initial argument in your field form.
For example:

```
name = forms.CharField(initial='Your name')
```

Here is documentation on this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial

Comment: Bu I'm use ModelForm. And, ok, if i add: "publish = forms.DateTimeField(initial=datetime.now())" — nothing happen.