# How to set default value to None for Django choices form field

Tags: django

The below Django form works, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make the ModelChoiceField for `operator` blank or set to `None` by default. I would like the user to have the option of just leaving this choices field set to `None`. This autopopulates with the first user in the user list.

**Model**

```
class Build(models.Model):
    PSScustomer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author =  models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),related_name='+',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null= True,)
    plannedAuthor =  models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,related_name='+',blank=True, null= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,)
    operator = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,related_name='+',blank=True, null= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

**View**

```
class queuedBuild_CreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Build
    form_class = queuedBuild_Creation_Form
    template_name = 'addQueuedBuild.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('equipmentdashboard')

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        customer = self.request.user.PSScustomer
        form.fields['operator'].choices = [(item.id, item.first_name) for item in CustomUser.objects.filter(isDevice=False, PSScustomer = customer)]
        return form
```

**Form**

```
class queuedBuild_Creation_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    buildDescrip = forms.ModelChoiceField(initial='Your name')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(queuedBuild_Creation_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['status'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Build
        fields = ['status', 'operator',]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as `None` is one of your choices you can do:

```
form.fields['operator'].initial = None
```

OR

```
choices = [(item.id, item.first_name) for item in CustomUser.objects.filter(isDevice=False, PSScustomer = customer)]

choices.insert(0, ('', 'None'))
form.fields['operator'].choices = choices
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values).

If not then you can use JavaScript to add a None choice and make it selected.

Comment: Thanks @Dean Elliot, I actually did try this, it does not change the default to None unfortunately...It doesn't seem to affect this field in any way

Comment: I've updated the answer, since `None` would now technically be a valid choice, you might want to create some custom validation to prevent the user submitting the form with `None` as a valid choice (if the field is not null), unless you want that.