# How to add value to django form template in html

Tags: html, django, templates

I created a django form and use it in html in user profile page.

{{profile_form.first_name}}

how can I add form value for this column of the form

I tried to add value from form widget but I need to add user data but I can only do it in html like user.first_name

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not possible to pass values into Django Form in template.

Rather than your can prefer passing it through views.

Reference: [Django set default form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values)

Comment: The problem is that I want to display current users info and user can edit it. In forms I do not know which user is it and cannot add value to widget

Comment: You can access the current logged in user's data using request.user in views and pass it through template. Example: first_name = request.user.first_name